# Array format for web service

Tags: php

I have 2 tables i.e `user` and `photo`. According to `user_id` get all the user details and all the photos from the photo table.

I am creating a  web-service using slim framework. How is it possible to make a array like above given format?

How to make a array like following format?

```
array(
   [id]=>
   [name]=>
   [email]=>
   [dob]=>
   [gallery]=>array(
                   [0] => 1.png
                   [1] => 2.png
                )
   [address]=> xyz
)
```

Comment: you have to first get the details from the tables and then need to manipulate them

Answer (score 0):

If your question is strictly about how to make the nested array, then here is a solution.

```
    // create the nested portion of the array
    $images = ['1.png', '2.png'];

    // create the rest of the array
    $result = [
        'id' => 1, 
        'name' => 'default', 
        'email' => '123@abc.com',
        'dob' => '3/4/89', 
        'gallery' => $images, 
        'address' => 'xyz'
    ];
```

Note how we set `'gallery' => $images`. If you need data from two different tables to be retrieved at the same time and formatted like this, then that would probably be easiest to achieve using a join in your query. If you need help with that just say so.